AC pipe wrap replacement
What type of insulation can I use to replace the rotted out K flex on my AC outside pipes? Will the normal pipe insulation from Home Depot be  o.k with some aluminum tape to protect it, or is it a special  higher heat type that I need?

The liquid refrigerant line is the warmer of the two lines. It should only be perhaps 5 °C warmer than the ambient air (outdoor temperature in cooling mode; indoor temperature during heating if it's a heat pump). There's no need for special or high-temperature insulation; any pipe insulation will do.
One special feature that HVAC line set insulation does offer is an outer coating which is resistant to UV degradation. Basic pipe insulation may break down relatively quickly if left exposed to sunlight. Aluminum tape seems like a fine choice to protect foam insulation from UV.
